# Extracting Keywords from a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to write a SQL query in SQL server that extracts certain keywords from a column holding string values.  The keywords are sitting in another Table -- (KEYWORDS). Also in case, there are multiple keywords found in the same string, I want all the keywords found to be displayed.

Egs

```
KEYWORDS -- Tom, Doctor, coach, value
TEXT -- Hi coach, tom here
```

Final O/p:

```
**TEXT**                           
Hi coach, tom here  

**KEYWORDS_EXTRACTED**
coach, tom
```

Comment: What is your database? Sql Server, MySQL...?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @k table(thekeyword varchar(50));
insert into @k(thekeyword) values ('Tom'), ('Doctor') , ('coach'), ('value');

declare @t table(thetext varchar(1000));
insert into @t(thetext) values('Hi coach, tom here'), ('Tom visited the doctor'), ('minicoach or minibus?'), ('Tomas says hi')

select *
from @t as t
outer apply
(
    select
    stuff(
    (select ',' + k.thekeyword
        --string_agg(k.thekeyword, ',') as thekeywords
    from @k as k
    where ' ' + t.thetext + ' ' like '%[^A-Za-z]'+k.thekeyword+'[^A-Za-z]%' --adjust
    for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as thekeywords
) as kw;
```

Comment: Is there  a way to do the same in SQL server 2014 i.e without the use of string_agg function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string_split()`:

```
select t.*, k.keyword
from t cross apply
     string_split(replace(text, ',', ' ')) s join
     keywords k
     on k.keyword = s.value;
```